# Order a JasperReports report by several columns

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to create a subgroup in iReport/JasperSoft Studio?

I have a report and I want to group it by name. Then inside that group I want to group it by street. 
Each time I group something by name the headers I start a new page reprint the headers. That's the point where I'm at. Now I want to group (inside the name group) by street so that the headers display again each time a new street is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use grouping on sorted data. If you need ordering by several columns you will have to pass it that way to Jasper and order the rows yourself either with multiple order columns in your SQL query or with custom Java code.

Comment: I'm passing the data through a JavaBean with which I set every field that I need in the report. I want to do 2 levels of grouping one with field name and another with field street

Comment: Then you will have to presort your bean collection that way before passing it to Jasper. You will not need to use Jasper grouping in the report.

Comment: I have a field which is named groupby and that way I know how I wil group and what. So there isn't a subgroup feature?

Comment: No, AFAIK, Jasper does not offer sorting by several columns.